# Proving Erdős–Szekeres theorem with chromatic number of graph

Tags: graph-theory

Here is Erdős–Szekeres theorem.

> Every sequence of $rs+1$ distinct real numbers has an increasing subsequence of size $r+1$ or decreasing subsequence of size $s+1$.

And I proved the following statement about an orientation of the graph.

> Let $D$ be an orientation of a graph $G$ with $\chi(G)>rs$. If we assign each $v \in V(D)$ a real number $f(v)$, then $D$ has a path $u_0\cdots u_r$ with $f(u_0)\leq\cdots\leq f(u_r)$ or a path $v_0\cdots v_s$ with $f(v_0) \geq \cdots \geq f(v_s)$.

I strongly guess that I can prove Erdős–Szekeres theorem by applying this statement to some proper $G$ with $\chi(G)=rs+1$.
But I have no idea with how to improve it.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed the graph we want is the complete graph $K_{rs+1}$ with vertices $\{1,2,\dots, rs+1\}$ where the orientation directs edge $\{i,j\}$ such that $\min(i,j)$ goes to $\max(i,j)$.

Now assume we have a list $f_1,\dots, f_{rs+1}$ , then this list can be seen as a function $f$ from $\{1,\dots,rs+1\}$ to $\mathbb R$ that sends each vertex to a real value.

In this graph a path is just a list of terms with increasing indices ( so a subsequence in the original list) . And the condition on the $f(v_i)$ gives us the monotonicity of the subsequence.